# Error logging into or signing up for Firebase

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase

This app was working just fine for quite some time, and I haven't changed any of the reference URL's, the keys are all correct etc. but now when I either log in or sign up with a new account the app crashes and I get this error, I put an exception breakpoint but it doesn't break anywhere, reverting immediately to the threads or main page so I'm not sure what "child" is an empty string. None that I can see are.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(childByAppendingPath:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
```

Here is the log in and sign up code, it doesn't even print the error in the error block and when I put a break point nothing happens inside the block. The base ref is correct and like I said this was working fine yesterday. Thank you for the help!

```
enum ViewMode {

    case LogIn
    case SignUp
}

var viewMode = ViewMode.SignUp

@IBAction func proceed(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch viewMode {

    case .LogIn:

        let emailString = usernameField.text
        let pwString = passwordField.text

        if emailString != "" && pwString != "" {

            DataService.sharedInstance.BASE_REF.authUser(emailString, password: pwString, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in

                if error != nil {

                    print(error.localizedDescription)

                    self.loginErrorAlert("Oops", message: "Something went wrong! Please try again")

                } else {

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: uidKey)

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(logInSegue, sender: nil)


                }

            })

        } else {

            loginErrorAlert("Oops", message: "Don't forget to enter both an Email and Password")

        }


    case .SignUp:

        //properties for our user

        let emailString = emailField.text
        let pwString = passwordField.text
        let username = usernameField.text
        let lastName = lastNameField.text
        let firstName = firstNameField.text

        if username != "" && emailString != "" && pwString != "" {

        DataService.sharedInstance.BASE_REF.createUser(emailString, password: pwString, withValueCompletionBlock: { (error, result) in

            if error != nil {

                print(error.localizedDescription)
                self.loginErrorAlert("Oops", message: "There was an error creating your account, please try again!")
            } else {

                DataService.sharedInstance.BASE_REF.authUser(emailString, password: pwString, withCompletionBlock: { (error, authData) in

                    let userDictionary = ["provider" : authData.provider!, "email" : emailString!, "username" : username!, "firstName" : firstName!, "lastName" : lastName!]

                    DataService.sharedInstance.createNewAccount(authData.uid, user: userDictionary)

                })

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(result["uid"], forKey: uidKey)

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(username, forKey: "usernameString")

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(signUpSegue, sender: self)
            }
        })


        } else {

            loginErrorAlert("Oops", message: "Don't forget to enter your email, a username and a password!")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There might be some problem in your createUser Or authUser Implementation

Comment: They were working fine like I said. I'm not sure what kind of problem it would be in that case, the internet was working fine too, I've tried restarting Xcode, the computer, deleting all the data from Firebase, checking every line of code and everything.

Comment: Yeah without seeing ur implementation of those I  see nothing here. I just see two string being passed to a function.

Comment: What do you mean? The implementation is what I posted. The createUser and authUser are built in firebase functions.